How to Set Different og:title for Facebook and LinkedIn?
I'm working on a web page where I need to customize how it appears when shared on social media.
From my understanding, both Facebook and LinkedIn use the Open Graph protocol, specifically the og:title tag, to display the title of the shared content. However, I'm unsure if it's possible to differentiate the og:title between these two platforms
I searched online but it shows that only twitter has its own og tags. FB and LinkedIN both use same

What you can do is use document.referrer to get the URL inside useEffect and check if the URL contains your required website. This solution is feels more generalized and does not limit to specific websites.
Add something like this in useEffect (dont forget to pass an empty array to useEffect)
    if (referrer.includes('facebook.com')) {
      // facebok meta data
    } 
    else if (referrer.includes('linkedin.com')) {
      // linkedin meta data
    }


I think social media platforms like Facebook and LinkedIn use server-side scrapers that do not execute client-side JavaScript. Because of this. The scrapers will grab the metadata directly from the HTML without executing any JavaScript, so any changes made using document.referrer or in useEffect won't be reflected in the shared content.

@AsadQureshi, you are correct, to parse OG you generally only need a HEAD request, which does not contain javascript. the canonical way of doing this is to have your webserver parse the user-agent of the request, notice that it is equal to a known UA from these companies and serve them different headers. The companies usually publish their user agent strings (e.g. Twitterbot/1.0) or you can easily find them online.
